# Basic Proxy Authentication on Electron

Tags: webview, electron

Is there any way to add username and password on session.setProxy on electron, here is what I am trying to do:

```
session.fromPartition("persist:sessionOne").setProxy({pacScript:"", proxyRules:"http://username:password@proxyIp:proxyPort", proxyBypassRules:""}, function() {});
```

But it is not working right now? I tried searching Electron Documentation but no luck. Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: solved this problem by using app on login event and filtering  the authinfo isProxy party.  `app.on('login', function(event, webContents, request, authInfo, callback) {
  if(authInfo.isProxy) {
    callback('username', 'password');
  }
})
`