# How to set Username and password to the proxy in Electron

Tags: electron

I have a question that seems easy but couldn't solve it.
How to set Username and password to the proxy in Electron?

I searched up on their documentation and tried a few solutions but no solution.
The page is blank and nothing is loading.
No error displaying or anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the comment on this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497982/basic-proxy-authentication-on-electron

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.